# In ul -> li -> a design li does not expand height to match a tag height

Tags: html, css

Can someone please explain to me, why li and ul does not expand in plunkr bellow?

*I know many has been written about that, but all I found is playing with overflow, height, position and display css properties. I do not use any of that.*

```css
a {
        padding: 1em;
        background-color: red;
      }
      ul {
        list-style: none;
        background-color: yellow;
        display: flex; 
      }
      
      li {
        background-color: green;
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="http://google.si">google</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="http://sometest.com">test item</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone please explain to me, why li and ul does not expand

Because your links are still inline, and therefor their padding flows out of the line box.

Add `display: block` for the links.

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:block` in `a` because `a` is an inline level element so make it block level

Also don't need `display:inline-block` in `li` because you have `display:flex` in `ul`

You can also remove default `padding` from `ul`

```css
a {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: red;
  display: block
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.si">google</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://sometest.com">test item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `a` is `inline` element, so it don't include `padding` in height, just update it to `block` label element. then `ul` and `li` will expend.
for updating it to `block label` you can add `display:block` or `display: inline-block` or `float: left`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display:block in anchor tag`

```css
      ul {
        list-style: none;
        background-color: yellow;
        display: flex; 
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
      }
      
     ul li {
        background-color: green;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      ul li a {
                padding: 1em;
        background-color: red;
        display:block;
      }
```

```html
<ul>
     <li>
       <a href="http://google.si">google</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="http://sometest.com">test item</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
```